# Multiple Operators in PHP If Statement

Tags: php

Just wanted to double check and make sure my line of thinking is correct. This hook runs every 48 hours, so I need to check if an event is happening today or tomorrow.

```
 $now = date('Y/m/d');
$today = explode("/", $now);
```

The event start date has the same format, but the value varies, and is stored the same way.

```
if ( $today[1] == $eventDate[1] &&
(intval($today[2]) == (intval($eventDate[2]-1)) || (intval($today[2]) == intval($eventDate[2])-2))) {

//run code

}
```

Comment: `$today` is a string. `$today[2]` is pulling the third value of that string, so the third value of the year. `$today[1]` is pulling the second value.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to copy a line. Please see edit

Comment: Why not execute the code and see if it's working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should consider to work with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) objects :

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$eventDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $eventDate);

if ($today->format('d-m-Y') === $eventDateTime->format('d-m-Y')) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to check that an event is happening today or tomorrow, you could do like this :

```
$start = new \DateTime();
$start->setTime(0,0,0);
$end = new \DateTime();
$end->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
$end->setTime(23,59,59);
$eventDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $eventDate);

if ($eventDateTime >= $start && $eventDateTime <= $end) {
    ...
}
```

This way you check if a date is in a certain period. Here I added 1 day to the current date but you can adapt the code and set more than 1 day if you want.

Comment: Wouldn't that only run the code if today's date matches the event date? I'm worried more about the multiple conditions to run the code if the today's date is the day before, or two days before the event.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what the benefits are to using a DateTime object vs. the method of date() that I used? Not being critical, really just curious!

Comment: I think this is more readable since you work directly with dates instead of strings which are supposed to be dates but you can't be sure about it, it's more testable moreover. Having a DateTime object also can allow you to display it in many different formats. I find it clearer to do $date->format('Y') than explode a string to display the third column of an array.